# What am I doing wrong with the Database Tuning Advisor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning

**My background**: I'm a dev/architect, not a DBA. Sorry!

So we have a ~400 table 75GB database. I ran Profiler for ~24 hours ("Tuning" template minus `LoginName`) and have ~7GB of usage recorded in a trace file. I then ran the Database Engine Tuning Advisor on this trace file (no partitioning, keep clustered indexes, PDS Recommend: Indexes) against our production database (after hours). I gave it ~4 hours to analyze. And here are the summary results I got:

[image: DTA Summary Results]

The things that stood out here to me that seem "wrong" are:

1. It only tuned ~9k out of ~530k queries
2. It recommended I drop a ton of indexes (in fact, most of them)
3. It recommended I create 0 indexes

Does this sound right to you guys? I expected it to drop most of my indexes but then to create a ton of new indexes. Also, if it takes 4 hours to analyze 9k queries, is it even feasible for me to get this to consider a normal day's worth of usage? Compared to most large databases, ours is fairly light on consumption (~50 users **total**).

I think I'm either misunderstanding something or am simply doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you expand on the nature of the database/workload? If you run the trace through [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/download.aspx), how many unique query signatures does it identify?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I haven't done a true analysis or used that tool, but I can very confidently say that there are a LOT of unique queries going on in there. This is a database in a line-of-business app for energy companies ranging from invoicing, quotes, customer management, and many other things. If it had 500k queries, I'd guess there would be at least 50k unique ones in there. It's quite a large system with a lot of different features. Just not a ton of users.

Comment: Also, if it had 50k unique queries, I'd say ~40-45k are derivatives of 5k "base" queries (just different WHERE clauses when users filter/sort tables of data by various columns and values). Not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with DTA. It's a whole lot of work for results that are sketchy at best. Everyone that gets into index tuning eventually realizes it's both a science and an art, and there's a lot to it. You can use tools to get recommendations, but implementing those recommendations blindly almost always results in issues down the road.

Instead, I'd give [BlitzIndex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) a try. It'll take advantage of the statistics SQL Server already maintains to determine where you can improve your indexing (and does so within seconds). It also provides very accessible documentation on how to use the results. Every result includes a link to the pertinent doc. This is how I maintain my indexes these days.

Comment: While I don't possess the skills to intelligently build indexes for our system, I was going to use what I do know to "interpret" the recommendations from DTA (not just blindly following them). I was going to go with maybe ~10% of its recommendations, re-analyze one more time to see if there are any obvious ones left to get, throw all of that against the wall, and see what sticks. I'll check out BlitzIndex to see what it thinks...

Comment: That is exactly what you should do when index tuning! You just need to find the right tool with recommendations you can work with. DTA is rarely that tool.

Comment: I've been trying to do this but that tool apparently isn't very useful after our nightly maintenance scripts run. Now that I've had a couple days and have disabled those maintenance scripts to keep usage stats around, this is proving to be a great tool! Thanks for recommending it!

Answer (score 0):

The BlitzIndex tool that @JMarx suggested is working great! However, I'm also finding this additional script to make some good suggestions as well. Not necessarily using all or even most of its suggestions, but cherry-picking from the top is proving very useful!

```
SELECT
  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure,
  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle)
  + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'
  + ' ON ' + mid.statement
  + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'')
    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END
    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
  + ')'
  + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement,
  migs.*, mid.database_id, mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
WHERE migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204043251/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx))

Another piece of info I've discovered is that both BlitzIndex and this script are worthless after a few events happening:

> **If you’re running SQL Server 2008 R2 or prior, this is index usage
> since either of the following, whichever is more recent:**
>
> 1. When the index was created
> 2. When SQL Server last started
>
> **If you’re running SQL Server 2012, this is index usage since any of
> the following:**
>
> 1. When the index was created
> 2. When SQL Server last started
> 3. When the index was rebuilt (specifically the rebuild command not reorganize)

([source](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/sp_blitz-column-definitions/))